# what happens when a DC fails? How can the clients identify DC failure?

Tags: active-directory, domain, domain-controller, subnet

When a DC fails, it loses the privilege to authenticate and so client will find for secondary DC closest to its site. In another scenario, client has selected a DC closest to its site by using subnet that is specified. In this case, when that DC fails how client will come to know that this DC is down and should look out for next closest DC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`when that DC fails how client will come to know that this DC is down and should look out for next closest DC?`

The client attempts to authenticate to the failed DC. When that authentication fails or times out, it moves on to the next DC.

Answer (score 0):

Various DNS entries define the combinations of domain controllers, sites, and subnets.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978011.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978016.aspx

Clients query DNS to locate domain controllers, both inside and outside of their site.